# MySQL custom sorting

Tags: sql

While writing a C# program I am trying to do a batch retrieval from a SQL database instead of getting each record one at a time.  This way I get all the records in one DataSet and can just hit the server once.  I have found that this method can be significantly faster.  However I need to maintain the order.  Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

```
SELECT [UserID], [LastName], [FirstName]
FROM [users]
WHERE [UserID] = '2024443' OR [UserID] = '2205659' OR [UserID] = '2025493';
```

**Edit:**

I need to obtain the data ordered in this way:

```
2024443
2205659
2025493
```

Comment: Which order? The only order that you can specify is through an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: You can also order them in C# as needed.

Comment: I am sorry I did not explain that clear enough.  They have to be in the order I have them list in my select statement left to right. So 2024443 then 2205659 and then 2025493.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why that order?  Is it really ordered by some other value in the records?  Seems a little arbitrary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate query to run would be:

```
SELECT [UserID], [LastName], [FirstName]
FROM [users]
WHERE [UserID] IN ('2024443', '2205659', '2025493')
ORDER BY [UserID]
```

Provided that you want to keep the order in the results for the `[UserID]` column.

**Edit after clarification on a very weird order the OP is looking for:**

So the expected output will have the selected rows in this order:

```
'2024443'
'2205659'
'2025493'
```

So a simple `ORDER BY` that will order as a character field won't be enough. You should clarify what order it is because clearly you just want to sort based on those 3 rows only (eg: you haven't clarified where you would like to have number `2100000` and it is unpredictable).

For these kind of sorting you could go for an awful solution that will only work on those rows but as I said before, that's all you've provided. So you can do something like this:

```
SELECT [UserID], [LastName], [FirstName]
FROM [users]
WHERE [UserID] IN ('2024443', '2205659', '2025493')
ORDER BY
    CASE [UserID]
        WHEN '2024443' THEN 0
        WHEN '2205659' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END
```

You should be able to build the rest of the queries with that custom sorting. Just follow this as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Does ORDER BY not work?

```
SELECT [UserID]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[FirstName]
FROM [users]
WHERE [UserID] = '2024443' OR [UserID] = '2205659' OR [UserID] = '2025493'
ORDER BY [UserID];
```

This will return the records you requested, sorted by UserID.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly, you are looking at retrieving the records in batches with specific batch size. In this case, you could retrieve the next set of records based on a primary key column index or a row number.